# Docker toolbox: Is there a way to mount other folders than from "C:\Users" Windows?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

I installed Docker toolbox 1.8.3 using VirtualBox 5.0.6 on Windows 7.

The *default* virtual machine created during startup of *Docker Quickstart Terminal* has one defined shared folder for `c:\Users`. Is it possible to persistently add other shared folders to this virtual machine e.g. mounting a `d:\` drive on the host?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [boot2docker README mentions](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/af8b089c8c528ed08ad2074c83f1756a5aeaa4ef/README.md#virtualbox-guest-additions)

> Alternatively, Boot2Docker includes the VirtualBox Guest Additions built in for the express purpose of using VirtualBox folder sharing.
>
> The first of the following share names that exists (if any) will be automatically mounted at the location specified:

```
c/Users share at /c/Users
/c/Users share at /c/Users
c:/Users share at /c/Users
```

> If some other path or share is desired, it can be mounted at run time by doing something like:

```
$ mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 your-other-share-name /some/mount/location
```

You can see more at [VirtualBox / Guest Additions / Shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)

> From the command line, you can create shared folders using VBoxManage, as follows:

```
VBoxManage sharedfolder add "boot2docker-vm" --name "sharename" --hostpath "C:\test"
```