# Laradock (container) files on Windows

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laradock

I installed docker `toolbox 1.11.2` and `Laradock v.2` cloned from GitHub.

Everything seems to work except the `laradock_workspace_1`. When is generated it does not create files on the host machine (`Windows 7 64-bit`). In the `docker-compose.yml` I have tried playing with the volumes as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399788/docker-cant-mount-folder-on-windows)

```
### Laravel Application Code Container ######################

    volumes_source:
        build: ./volumes/application
        volumes:
            - ../:/var/www/laravel
```

If I change the last line to `../..` then run `docker-compose up`, `docker exec -it laradock_workspace_1 ls` and I can see that it is traversing the folders on the host machine. I just don't see any files.

My goal here is to make the actual Laravel code external so I can edit them on the host machine and use `git`.

I can use the `Kitematic` app to make the changes I want but they seem lost if I do a `docker-compose down`. (and I get errors about things still being in use.)

I'm new to `docker` so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your docker-machine is running. If it is, then follow below:

Open up Virtualbox GUI and right click your docker vm, and select settings, then go to Shared Folders.

Change the c\users to whatever folder your code lies in, like this:
[image]

This will mount your desired folder to /c/Users in the docker-machine vm.

After this, change the docker-compose.yml in the laradock folder to this:

```
### Laravel Application Code Container ######################

    volumes_source:
        build: ./volumes/application
        volumes:
            - /c/Users/pomodoro.xyz/code:/var/www/laravel
```

The logic behind this is, since we are running the docker in a VM, the docker-compose command **looks for folder in the VM**, not in the windows machines. Thats why we have provided the VM machine path to the docker-compose file.