# Docker compose and ansible: site.yml does not appear to be a file

Tags: docker, ansible

Im building a docker-compose service that probes for my db service to start before starting a test on my app. The docker-compose files worked great and I just created a new host with a docker machine and now I get an error when running:

```
docker-compose up agent
```

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
test:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes_from:
    - cache
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: todobackend.settings.test
    MYSQL_HOST: db
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    TEST_OUTPUT_DIR: /reports

builder:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ../../target:/wheelhouse
  volumes_from:
    - cache
  entrypoint: "entrypoint.sh"
  command: ["pip", "wheel", "--no-index", "-f /build", "."] 

agent:
  image: pjestrada/ansible
  volumes:
    - ../../ansible/probe.yml:/ansible/site.yml
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    PROBE_HOST: "db"
    PROBE_PORT: "3306"

db:
  image: mysql:5.6
  hostname: db
  expose:
    - "3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

cache:
    build: ../../
    dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /tmp/cache:/cache
      - /build
    entrypoint: "true"
```

my playbook:

```
---
- name: Probe Host
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Set facts
    set_fact:
      probe_host: "{{ lookup('env', 'PROBE_HOST') }}"
      probe_port: "{{ lookup('env', 'PROBE_PORT') }}"
      probe_delay: "{{ lookup('env', 'PROBE_DELAY') | default(0, true) }}"
      probe_timeout: "{{ lookup('env', 'PROBE_TIMEOUT') | default (180, true) }}"
  - name: Message
    debug:
      msg: >
        Probing {{ probe_host }}:{{ probe_port }} with delay={{ probe_delay }}s
        and timeout={{ probe_timeout }}s 
  - name: Waiting for hosts to respond...
    local_action: >
      wait_for host={{ probe_host }}
      port={{ probe_port }}
      delay={{ probe_delay }}
      timeout={{ probe_timeout }}
```

and my ansible Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Pablo Estrada <pjestradac@gmail.com>

# Prevent dpkg errors
ENV TERM=x-term-256color


RUN sed -i "s/http:\/\/archive./http:\/\/nz.archive./g" /etc/apt/sources.list


#Install ansible

RUN apt-get update -qy && \
    apt-get install -qy software-properties-common && \
    apt-add-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible && \
    apt-get update -qy && \
    apt-get install -qy ansible

# Add voulme for Ansible Playbooks
Volume /ansible
WORKDIR /ansible




#Entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["ansible-playbook"]
CMD ["site.yml"]
```

The error I get says: ERROR! the playbook: site.yml does not appear to be a file

I dont understand why this happens if Im mapping the probe.yml to site.yml on my docker compose file. Is there anything wrong with my images?? Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**

Aparently the issue happens when I start my docker machine and use

```
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

this is my docker machine info:

```
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.12.1
```

When everything worked I did not have any docker host up with docker-machine. What can be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you've specified a path to a `probe.yml` that doesn't exist on the VM, and docker (being helpful) created a directory and mounted that for you.

```
○ →ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  110 13 Sep 05:26 docker-compose.yml

○ →docker-compose run agent ansible-playbook site.yml
ERROR! the playbook: site.yml does not appear to be a file

○ →ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  110 13 Sep 05:26 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 user  staff   68 13 Sep 05:31 site.yml
```

The directory you are using locally might not be shared to the VM? Although you should have a lot more than just the `agent` failing if that were the case.

#### Sharing from linux to a local VM

To quote [the git repo](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions)

> In case it isn't already clear, the Linux host support here is currently hazy.

It sounds like sharing `/home` as a [shared folder](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) called `/Users` will allow your home directories to be automounted in the local Docker VM. If you create a link to `/home` called `/Users` and run your docker commands from there that will make the directory paths look the same in both the VM and local machine, and Docker should be happy.

```
ln -s /home /Users
VBoxManage sharefolder add "default" --name "/Users" --hostpath "/Users"
cd /Users/you/project
eval $(docker-machine env default)
docker-compose run whatever
```

Comment: Its very likely that i dont have share the folders. How do I specify the folders to share to my docker-machine?

Comment: Docker Toolbox (boot2docker) will share the `/Users` or `C:/Users` directories by default into the vm as `/Users` or `/c/Users`. Other than that you have to set it up manually: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33245360

Comment: and from memory it's hard to persist custom shares in boot2docker

Comment: Whats the best way to go about it on Linux? Im using ubuntu