# how to mount localhost volume to a docker container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise

```
Docker Client version:
 Version:      1.12.2
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   bb80604
 Built:        Tue Oct 11 17:00:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Docker Server version:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 23:26:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

docker-compose version:
docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
docker-py version: 1.10.6
CPython version: 2.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

I couldn't figure out how to mount volumes in docker-compose.yml file when using a docker toolbox on windows.

Below is the `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '2'
services:
    myapp:
        build:
           context: .
           args:
               ADMIN_PASS= welcome1
        ports:
         - "7001:8001"
        volumes:
         - "/C/myapp/gradleBuild/myappEar/libs:/myappEar"
```

when I run `docker-compose up` below is the error I'm getting

```
ERROR: for myapp Cannot create container for service myapp: create \C\myapp\gradleBuild\myappEar\libs: "\\C\\myapp\\gradleBuild\\myappEar\\libs" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed
←[31mERROR←[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

when I change the volumes section to

```
volumes:
   - "/c/myapp/gradleBuild/myappEar/libs:/myappEar"
```

It throws the same error

And when I finally change the volumes section to

```
volumes:
  - "C:/myapp/gradleBuild/myappEar/libs:/myappEar"
```

It throws the below error

```
ERROR: for myapp Cannot create container for service myapp: Invalid bind mount spec "C:\\myapp\\gradleBuild\\myappEar\\libs:/myappEar:rw": Invalid volume specification: 'C:/myapp/gradleBuild/myappEar/libs:/myappEar:rw'
←[31mERROR←[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Can anyone please help me get through this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you are using [docker toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox) (meaning docker through a VirtualBox VM), only `/c/users/mylogin` is available by default.
You need to [declare other mount locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33245360/6309) if your path does not include `c:\Users\myLogin`.

You access more of the C drive only through [HyperV VM](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/) on Windows 10 (which you don't have, since you are on Windows 7).

Comment: I added the `myapp` folder in the `/c/Users/<username>/myapp` and changed the `docker-compose` file and tried running the `docker-compose up` but, still having same error 

`ERROR: for myapp Cannot create container for service myapp: create \c\Users\mreddy\myapp\gradleBuild\myappEar\libs: "\\c\\Users\\mreddy\\myapp\\gradleBuild\\myappEar\\libs" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed
←[31mERROR←[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Answer (score 1):

In your docker-compose image you have mounted the volume as such:

> volumes:
>     - "/C/myapp/gradleBuild/myappEar/libs:/myappEar"

On windows it is mentioned to mount docker volumes using the format below:

```
c:\<path>:/c:\<container path>
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)

Comment: I did that too. But, no luck it throws a different error saying `Invalid volume specification`

Comment: what type of image are you mounting too?

Comment: it is a weblogic image which uses the files in the `C:/Users/mreddy/myapp` folder to deploy the application on to the WL Server.